# Pandas: Compare dataframes for additional and changed rows

Tags: python, pandas, compare

This might be a really stupid thing to ask but I have two pandas dataframes such that

df1

```
         USR_ID  RELATIONSHIP_ID    
0           49                2    
1           50               58    
2           52                2    
3           52               58
```

df2

```
         USR_ID  RELATIONSHIP_ID    
0           49                1     
1           50               58     
2           52                3     
3           52               58
4           52                2
```

df2 can have extra rows but the guarantee is that both df1 and df2 will have the same and exact USR_ID. I wish to track the changes between df1 and df2. In this case -

- USR_ID 49 has different relationships (2 and 1)
- USR_ID 52 has an additional relationship 3

So what I would like back is a dataframe with:

```
       USR_ID     RELATIONSHIP_ID_1    RELATIONSHIP_ID_2
0          49                2          1 
1          52        Does not exist     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC using `groupby` with `set` for each dfs then we do a comparison

```
s1=df1.groupby('USR_ID')['RELATIONSHIP_ID'].apply(set)
s2=df2.groupby('USR_ID')['RELATIONSHIP_ID'].apply(set)
[(x-y)|(y-x) for x , y in zip(*pd.concat([s1,s2],1).values.T)]

Out[585]: [{1, 2}, set(), {3}]
```

Update

```
i1=[(x-y) for x , y in zip(*pd.concat([s1,s2],1).values.T)]
i2=[(y-x) for x , y in zip(*pd.concat([s1,s2],1).values.T)]
pd.DataFrame({'RELATIONSHIP_ID_1':list(map(list,i1)),'RELATIONSHIP_ID_2':list(map(list,i2))},index=s1.index).apply(lambda x : x.str[0]).dropna(thresh=1)
Out[646]: 
        RELATIONSHIP_ID_1  RELATIONSHIP_ID_2
USR_ID                                      
49                    2.0                1.0
52                    NaN                3.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain a relatiosnhip with the user_id. What I would like back is a dataframe as shown in the edits to my question

Comment: @Fizi let me look into it